# Approximate inclusion-Exclusion?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, counting-complexity, set-cover, approximation

I am trying to understand or find literature on the following problem of approximate inclusion exclusion.

Let $S:=\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{m}$ be a set of $m$ sets. Every intersection of $k$ elements in $S$ have the cardinality $\alpha_k$. Then using principle of inclusion-exclusion, we have that:
$$\textstyle\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^{m}A_i\right| = \sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{m}{k}\alpha_k$$

The problem:

Given an probabilistically approximately correct estimate of each $\alpha_k$, say $\bar{\alpha}_k$. I.e.
$$\mathrm{Pr}(|\alpha_k - \bar{\alpha}_k| \leq \epsilon \alpha_k) \geq 1-\delta$$
For some $0 <\epsilon <1$ and $0 <\delta <1$.With som abuse of notation, I denote $|\cup_{i=1}^{m}A_i|$ as $|S|$. And I denote $\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{m}{k}\bar{\alpha}_k$ as $|\bar{S}|$ (Not that, $|\bar{S}|$ is my estimate for $|S|$). I would like to understand if there exist any gaurentees of the type:

$$Pr[| |S| - |\bar{S}| |\leq \epsilon |S| ] > 1-\delta$$

Adjacent but not exactly the same problems:

1. [Paper 1](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Enati/PAPERS/approx_incl_excl.pdf)
2. [Paper 2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01271266?noAccess=true)

Comment: what is your instance space? concept class? Since we're talking about PAC.

Comment: You've asked whether there is a guarantee of the type $$\Pr[| |S| - |\bar{S}| |\geq \epsilon |S| ] > 1-\delta.$$  Have you reversed an inequality there?

Comment: @NealYoung Thanks, that was a mistake!

Comment: It seems you need some stronger assumptions to get any such bound.  E.g. consider $S=A_i = \emptyset$ for $i\in[m]$, so $\alpha_k = 0$ for all $k$.  Choose a $k'$ uniformly at random in $[m]$ and set $\overline \alpha_{k'} = 1$, while setting all other $\overline \alpha_{k} = 0$.  Then, for any $k\in [m]$, $\Pr[|\alpha_k - \overline \alpha_k| = 0] = 1-1/m$, but $\Pr[|S| = |\overline S|] = 0$ (for example).